# Why does marginalization not work for continuous random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let a set of outcomes be $A$ such that $P(A)\neq 0$ and let a random variable on the sample space $\Omega$ be $X$.

If X is discrete, then marginalization states that
$$
P(A) = \sum_{x\in codomain(X)} P(A,X=x)
$$
However, if X is continuous, then
\begin{align}
P(A) &= \int_{x\in codomain(X)} P(A,X=x)dx\\
&= \int_{x\in codomain(X)} P(A|X=x)P(X=x)dx\\
&= 0
\end{align}
which must be false since $P(A)\neq 0$. Why is this the case? Is the following explanation correct?
\begin{align}
P(A)&=P(A\cap\Omega)\\
&=P(A\cap\cup_{x\in codomain(X)}X^{-1}(x))\\
&\neq \sum_{x\in codomain(X)} P(A\cap X^{-1}(x))
\end{align}
since indexing set is uncountable. Furthermore, if the last equality holds, then the sum is not a Riemann integral, again because the indexing set is uncountable.

Comment: Why do you think $P(A) = \int_{\mathbb R}P(A,X=x)\,dx$? It clearly doesn't since $P(X=x) = 0$. And moreover, what does $P(A\mid X=x)$ even mean? $P(X=x) = 0$.

Comment: In my example I tried to demonstrate that blindly applying the same strategy in the continuous case as in the discrete case is incorrect, precisely because P(X=x)=0. The notation P(A|X=x) denotes the conditional probability of event A given that event X=x happens. After showing that the formula is false, I try finding where in deriving such a formula fails. I do this by using the same strategy as in the discrete case, where instead the index set of the union is countable.

Comment: $P(A\mid X=x)\overset{\vartriangle}{=}P(A,X=x)/P(X=x) = 0/0$

Comment: I understand. What do you think about my subsequent derviation with the uncountable union?

Comment: Looks good to me, although I'm not familiar with uncountable sums, and whether it even makes sense to talk about it here.

Comment: assuming that $X$ assumes a probability density function, what's wrong with $f_X(x)=\int f_{X,Y}(x,y) d y$?

Answer (score 1):

The correct formula is $$P(A) = E(P(A \mid X)) = \int P(A | X = x)P(X \in dx).$$
This works for any random variable $X$. If $X$ has density function $f$, meaning $P(X \in dx) = f(x)\,dx$, then we get $$P(A) = \int P(A \mid X = x)f(x)\,dx.$$

Comment: I have never seen an integral like $\int P(A|X=x)P(X\in dx)$. Does it have a name?

Comment: @Angelos It is integration with respect to the measure $P(X \in \cdot)$, which is called the distribution of $X$. Sometimes people write $dP_X(x)$ instead of $P(X \in dx)$. See chapter 1 of https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/pte.html